# Use JQuery to highlight cell when text is typed into a text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to highlight table cells as text is typed into an input.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#search').keyup(function() {

     var value = $('#search').val();
     $('td:contains(value)').css({'border-color':'red'});

  });
});
```

I don't understand why this is not working, please help me understand!

EDIT: #search is a text input where the search term is entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're searching for the string `value`, not for the contents of the variable `value`. Use concatenation to put the variable's value into your selector:

```
$('td:contains(' + value + ')').css({'border-color':'red'});
```

---

Edit:

You also need to set the other border properties:

```
$('td:contains(' + value + ')').css({border: 'red 1px solid'});
```

Note also that this has fairly odd behaviour.  The moment I type a letter into the input box, this code will highlight every `td` that contains that letter. Deleting the contents of the input has no effect.  If you want a different effect, you'll have to say what it is. Whole words, perhaps?

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I was planning on evolving the functionality of the code myself. Selecting the correct td was the first hurdle for me. Obviously its working for you so it must be something else, Ill comb over my code.. thanks again.

Comment: Jees that was an embarresing mistake.. your right, I didnt define the border! Many thanks!